# Applescript to connect to bluetooth device

Tags: mac, bluetooth, applescript, automator, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to create an applescript to allow me to connect to a bluetooth device by it's Bluetooth ID.

So far, i've managed to get an applescript to turn on bluetooth if it's off. Here's the code:

```
# This is only necessary, if AppleScripts are not yet allowed to change checkboxes
tell application "System Events" to set UI elements enabled to true
# Now change the bluetooth status
  tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preferences.bluetooth"
      tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
        # Enabled is checkbox number 2
        if value of checkbox 2 of window "Bluetooth" is 0 then
            click checkbox 2 of window "Bluetooth"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit
end tell
```

Would someone know if and how it's possible to set up a new bluetooth device and if it'd be posible to connect to a device based on it's device name/ it's device bluetooth ID?

I've also tried to record the action in Automator but for the "set up new device" option, Automator just tells me: "click on "" button". 
Thanks

Comment: Found your question via Google because I'm hoping to find a solution as well. If I have any luck I'll be sure to post an answer here (though things aren't looking promising).

Comment: Please check [this](https://coderwall.com/p/fyfp0w/applescript-to-connect-bluetooth-headphones).

Comment: @mu3 can you add that as an actual answer? I almost missed that there's a solution to this question.

Answer (score 6):

I've manage to do it thanks to [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/fyfp0w/applescript-to-connect-bluetooth-headphones) provided by @mu3 in the comments. Here is the Apple Script :

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        -- Working CONNECT Script.  Goes through the following:
        -- Clicks on Bluetooth Menu (OSX Top Menu Bar)
        --    => Clicks on device Item
        --      => Clicks on Connect Item
        set btMenu to (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "bluetooth")
        tell btMenu
            click
            tell (menu item "Beats Solo³ de Anthonin" of menu 1)
                click
                if exists menu item "Connect" of menu 1 then
                    click menu item "Connect" of menu 1
                    return "Connecting..."
                else
                    key code 53 -- Close main BT drop down if Connect wasn't present
                    return "Connect menu was not found, are you already connected?"
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

All you have to do is replacing "Beats Solo³ de Anthonin" with your device name, and if your computer isn't in English, replace "Connect" with its translation in your language.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Worked great, and it integrates with no changes into an Alfred Workflow.  
Many thanks 

Comment: Just FYI - I found this to work GREAT on a 2017 MBP running Mojave, but it did not work on my 2011 iMac running High Sierra - the Connect menu item just isn't present.